# Determine two vectors so that any vector in null space A can be a linear combination of these two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, calculus-of-variations

For the given matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 5 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 4 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$, the RREF was found to be: $$x_1 = -2x_3 - 3x_4$$ $$x_2 = -x_3 + 2x_4$$ $$x_3,x_4 = free$$

How would we determine two vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$ such that any vector in the null space $A$ could be written as a linear combination of those two vectors. Similarly, how would we determine two vectors that would could fulfill the same condition in the range space $A$?

Comment: In general: fix a free variable, set it equal to $1$, set the rest of the free variables to $0$, and get a vector in the nullspace. Do that for each free variable and you will get a basis for then nullspace. Once you have a basis for the nullspace, extend it to a basis of the domain, and the images of the *added* vectors give a basis for the range.

Comment: Just give values to $x_3,x_4$ so that the two vectors are linearly independent. Say, the first vector is $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(7,0,-2,-1)$, and the second one $(0,7,-3,2)$ (  I like integer coordinates).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Could you elaborate on the part regarding the range space? I'm a bit confused on what that means.

Comment: If $S$ spans the domain, then the vectors $As$, with $s$ ranging over all elements of $S$, spans the range. If $n_1,\ldots,n_k$ are a basis for the nullspace, and you extend it to a basis for the domain, $n_1,\ldots,n_k,v_{k+1},\ldots v_m$, then the range is spanned by $An_1,\ldots,An_k,Av_{k+1},\ldots,Av_{m}$. But $An_1=\cdots=An_k=\mathbf{0}$, so they can be omitted, and the range is  simply spanned by $Av_{k+1},\ldots, Av_{m}$.